# @@ERROR Always Equals Zero

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following code:

```
BEGIN TRY
   EXEC (@action_sql);
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   SELECT @change_id AS ChangeId,
          @action_sql AS sqlAttempted,
          ERROR_MESSAGE () AS ErrorMessage,
          ERROR_NUMBER () AS ErrorNumber,
          ERROR_SEVERITY () AS ErrorSeverity,
          ERROR_LINE () AS ErrorLine;
END CATCH;

IF @@ERROR = 0
   BEGIN
      PRINT '@@ERROR = ' + CAST (@@ERROR AS VARCHAR (10))
      PRINT 'COMMIT';
      COMMIT TRANSACTION;
   END
ELSE
   BEGIN
      PRINT '@@ERROR = ' + CAST (@@ERROR AS VARCHAR (10))
     PRINT 'ROLLBACK';
     ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
   END;
```

When I put a valid or invalid SQL statement in `@action_sql` I always get printed

```
@@ERROR = 0
COMMIT
```

`@@ERROR` always returns zero even if `action_sql` is invalid.

What is the easiest way to determine if some sort of error took place?

Thanks,

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the @@Error would be associated with the `Exec(@action_sql)` and you would have to capture it immediately after it's execution to capture the @@Error value. You are running another `Select` statement between the try logic and capturing the @@Error in the catch logic and since that `Select` obviously succeeds it would have an @@Error code of zero. Try creating an `INT` variable and do `SET @Error = @@Error` as the first thing you do in the catch block and change your comparison in the `IF` logic to check against @Error instead of @@Error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because the value for `@@ERROR` is getting reset to `0` i.e. no error after you've captured and handled it in your `TRY CATCH` block. So the right way to do this is to capture and store the error values (if any) in variables, and then use those variables to take further action based on whether or not the variables indicate that an error happened.

See sample code below. The `@action_sql` is invalid in 1st case, and you will see the error code printed out. In the second case, the `@action_sql` is valid and you won't see any error code printed out.

1st Sample: Invalid `@action_sql`.

```
declare @action_sql NVARCHAR(2000);
declare @change_id INT
declare @ErrorNumber int
declare @ErrorMessage  NVARCHAR(2000);

set @action_sql  = 'select * from sysobj;'

BEGIN TRY
   EXEC (@action_sql);
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH    
          SELECT 
          @ErrorMessage =  ERROR_MESSAGE(),
          @ErrorNumber = ERROR_NUMBER()
          -- ERROR_SEVERITY () AS ErrorSeverity,
          -- ERROR_LINE () AS ErrorLine;
END CATCH;

IF @ErrorNumber = 0
   BEGIN
      PRINT '@@ERROR = ' + CAST (@ErrorNumber AS VARCHAR (10))
      PRINT 'COMMIT';
      --COMMIT TRANSACTION;
   END
ELSE
   IF (@ErrorNumber > 0)
   BEGIN
      PRINT '@@ERROR = ' + CAST (@ErrorNumber AS VARCHAR (10))
     PRINT 'ROLLBACK';
     --ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
   END;
```

2nd Sample: Valid `@action_sql`

```
declare @action_sql NVARCHAR(2000);
declare @change_id INT
declare @ErrorNumber int
declare @ErrorMessage  NVARCHAR(2000);

set @action_sql  = 'select top 10 * from sysobjects;'

BEGIN TRY
   EXEC (@action_sql);
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH    
          SELECT 
          @ErrorMessage =  ERROR_MESSAGE(),
          @ErrorNumber = ERROR_NUMBER()
          -- ERROR_SEVERITY () AS ErrorSeverity,
          -- ERROR_LINE () AS ErrorLine;
END CATCH;

IF @ErrorNumber = 0
   BEGIN
      PRINT '@@ERROR = ' + CAST (@ErrorNumber AS VARCHAR (10))
      PRINT 'COMMIT';
      --COMMIT TRANSACTION;
   END
ELSE
   IF (@ErrorNumber > 0)
   BEGIN
      PRINT '@@ERROR = ' + CAST (@ErrorNumber AS VARCHAR (10))
     PRINT 'ROLLBACK';
     --ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
   END;
```

Answer (score 2):

The `@@ERROR` function is populated as soon as an error occurs and if there is any other statement executing after this function its values is reset to `NULL` so you have to use a variable to capture the value of @@ERROR function after you have executed your statement,

So to anticipate where an error can occur and then Store its value to a Variable is really an over kill when you have `TRY..CATCH` blocks.

Since you are using `TRY..CATCH` blocks, you really dont need to use @@ERROR function. just change the order of your code a little bit.

something like this...

```
BEGIN TRY
 BEGIN TRANSACTION

   EXEC (@action_sql); --<-- if an error occurs here control jumps to catch block and
                          -- following lines of code never gets executed. (I mean in case of an error)
   PRINT 'COMMIT';        
   COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
 IF @@TRANCOUNT <> 0      --<-- Once an error occurred check for any open trans
   ROLLBACK TRANSACTION      -- if there is one ROLLBACK it.

   SELECT @change_id AS ChangeId,         --<-- Rest of the ERROR Functions 
          @action_sql AS sqlAttempted,
          ERROR_MESSAGE () AS ErrorMessage,
          ERROR_NUMBER () AS ErrorNumber,
          ERROR_SEVERITY () AS ErrorSeverity,
          ERROR_LINE () AS ErrorLine;
END CATCH;
```

Now since you have `BEGIN` an `Explicit Transaction` in your `TRY` block if any error occurs the executing will stop there and the control will jump to `CATCH` block.

Then there you can check for any OPEN TRANSACTIONs using `@@TRANCOUNT` and if open just roll back it and get all the other info about the error using ERROR MESSAGES.